# In what order Set items are sorted when converting to Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, set

I'm interested in what criteria are used to sort Set when converting? And how can this be overridden? Because, as I understand it, Set does not store sorting information. An example of the conversion I'm talking about:

```java
    Set<Object> objectsSet = new HashSet<>();
    Objects[] objectsArray = (Objects[]) objectsSet.toArray();
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toArray(), specifically regarding iteration order.

Answer (score 4):

Not sorted. `LinkedHashSet` preserves insertion order; `HashSet` is going to be ordered by the `hashCode()` internally. If you want a sorted `Set`, use a `TreeSet` (which implements `SortedSet`).

```
SortedSet<Object> objectsSet = new TreeSet<>();
Objects[] objectsArray = (Objects[]) objectsSet.toArray();
```

As for changing the order (ascending or descending), you can use [`TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-) when constructing the `Set`. For example, to sort integers in reverse order;

```
SortedSet<Integer> intSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Set.toArray` method Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#toArray()) specify the iteration behavior of a given `Set`:

> If this set makes any guarantees as to what order its elements are returned by its iterator, this method must return the elements in the same order.

One thing that is specifically left undefined is the order of elements in the array if the set does not guarantee the order of elements returned by the iterator.

If the set has a well-defined encounter order (e.g. it implements the [`SequencedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html) interface added in Java 21), then the order of the elements in the array will match the encounter order of that type of set.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second part of the question, the ordering could be overridden by sorting as part of a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream()) operation that constructs the array:

```java
Comparator<Object> myComparator = // ... Something that sorts this type of value
objectsSet.stream().sorted(someComparator).toArray();
```